# Calculate Ratio of two different SQL queries result that return numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have Query 1

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) total_daily_active_user_group_month FROM (SELECT  user_id , MONTHNAME(time) mon , COUNT(*) cnt FROM ACTIVITIES 
WHERE  MONTH(time) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) GROUP by user_id, MONTH(time) ) as x
```

Returns 18

Query 2

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) total_daily_active_user_group_month FROM (SELECT  user_id , MONTHNAME(time) mon , COUNT(*) cnt FROM ACTIVITIES 
WHERE  MONTH(time) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) GROUP by user_id, MONTH(time) having cnt=31) as x
```

Return 6

I want the ratio of query 1 and two. Means

18/6 . I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

If you use both queries as CTEs, then it becomes relatively simple:

```
WITH q1
     AS (SELECT Count(DISTINCT user_id) total_daily_active_user_group_month
         FROM   (SELECT user_id,
                        Monthname(TIME) mon,
                        Count(*)        cnt
                 FROM   activities
                 WHERE  Month(TIME) = Month(Now() - interval 1 month)
                 GROUP  BY user_id,
                           Month(TIME))),
     q2
     AS (SELECT Count(DISTINCT user_id) total_daily_active_user_group_month
         FROM   (SELECT user_id,
                        Monthname(TIME) mon,
                        Count(*)        cnt
                 FROM   activities
                 WHERE  Month(TIME) = Month(Now() - interval 1 month)
                 GROUP  BY user_id,
                           Month(TIME)
                 HAVING cnt = 31))
SELECT q1.total_daily_active_user_group_month /
       q2.total_daily_active_user_group_month
       AS result
FROM   dual;
```

---

You commented that you got an error pointing to the `WITH` keyword; switch to two subqueries, then; simplified:

```
select a.value / b.value as result 
from (select count(distinct user_id) value
      from ... your 1st query goes here
     ) a,
     (select count(distinct user_id) value
      from ... your 2nd query goes here
     ) b;
```

Comment: I have error in mySQL. at line 9 and in WITH .

Comment: Switch to 2 subqueries, then (see edited code).

Comment: Got it. Thank you very Much